# Does Spotify for Android broadcast meta data?

Tags: android, spotify

I'm trying to find a way to support meta data for Spotify in my music visualization app.  Many other apps broadcast their own action each time a new song plays, and the action includes extras with meta data for the song.

Also, many apps broadcast using Last.fm's action for meta data. They do this so Last.fm can scrobble them, but it is also useful for me to pick up the meta data.

Does Spotify support meta data broadcasts?

Comment: Their website directs here for Spotify questions. I'm assuming/hoping they have someone that monitors the Spotify tag here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no - the Spotify Android app doesn't do this.

Comment: Do you think something like this might come in the future? Music visualizers are increasing in popularity, now that Gingerbread (which supports them) has become widespread.